# mysql table doesn't exist, and how to fix it

Tags: mysql

2 Notes:

- This is for a Windows installation.
- I'm stupid.

In the process of cleaning up some stuff that was entirely unrelated, I accidentally deleted the directory `/mysql/data/[database]`, with all the .frm and .idb files.

Move ahead a few hours, when I tried to utilize that database and it didn't work.  I couldn't figure it out, so I ended up going into mySQL Workbench and dropping the table from there.

I then realized what I had done, so I went into recycle bin, got the files I had deleted, and recreated the physical directory at `/mysql/data/[database]` and pasted the files there, then reloaded MySQL Workbench - I hit refresh, and I saw the database there, but I can't access anything - it says the tables are all empty.

The good thing is that I have an .sql file of the database that I generated earlier today - I've tried importing it through MySQL workbench and I get the `"table doesn't exist"` error.

The entire installation contains about 9 different databases for 9 different projects - only this 1 was affected.

What's the best way to go about fixing this?  Since I have a valid .sql file containing this database, I'm more than happy to export the other 8 databases and then completely re-create the installation using these .sql files - I've just never done that and I'm not sure how to go about it.

If there's an easier way, I'll take that first. :)

Comment: Stopping MySQL and restarting should resolve it. InnoDB will re-read the table information and you should be able to access. I have done this a few times myself. If the process will not stop normally, kill it and InnoDB will start a crash recovery.

Comment: stopped, restarted.  Refreshed phpmyadmin - clicked on the database - "No tables found in database."  Click on the table (that shows up in phpmyadmin): "#1146 - Table [database.table] doesn't exist."

Comment: Do the .sql files contain both the structure and data?

Comment: @akuzminsky Yes - the .sql files contain both.

Comment: Then I would `DROP [database]` and reload it from the dumps.

Comment: @BrianPowell, can you create the missing table manually in the affected db from the workbench? Just create it and leave it empty and then try to import the db from .sql file.

Comment: `drop database ltc Error Code: 1010. Error dropping database (can't rmdir '.\ltc', errno: 41) `

Comment: @bangal - I could, but the database contains 6 tables with a lot of rows, I was hoping I wouldn't have to manually re-create them if I was just going to get the same error.  i wasn't sure if that would work so I hadn't tried it yet.

Comment: 41 means `Directory not empty` remove all files from `ltc` first.

Comment: suh wEEEEEEEEEEEET.  That worked.  You guys are my heroes!!  That saves me hours!